Firebase Altering Data
Before sending data to firebase realtime database, it's right, but after I make the request, the data returned is incorrect.
for year in data:
  for month in data[year]:
    requests.put(f'{firebase}{year}/{month}.json', json=data[year][month])

The data variable is structured in this format
{
  "data": {
    "2024": {
      "9": {
        "1": []

Firebase response:
{
  "data": {
    "2023": {
      "9": [null, null, null, null, null, null, ...

where 2024 is the year, 9 is the month, and 1 is the day. When I print data[year][month] out before the request, it prints out the dictionary of days in the month which is correct. However, after making the request to firebase, it returns a list of days?? With the first couple of values being None. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any help is appreciated!

When a node's object keys look like numbers that start small, Realtime Database assumes that it's meant to be an array, and gives you data back as an array with the keys converted to list indices.  You will have to manually convert it to dict instead, if that's what you want.  (Firebase did not modify the data - you are just getting it back differently.) Or find a more natural way to store the data (perhaps by using a formatted timestamp string as the unique key, instead of nested objects of time part numbers).  This is the behavior for all languages with a Firebase SDK.
